# Select2 JQuery issue with ASP.NET UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, jquery-select2

Have a existing solution I have been asked to enhance with Select2 JQuery library.

Have an `updatepanel` with a save button.  On that `updatepanel` is a ASP.NET `DropDownList`.

on document ready I issue

```
$('.dropdownspecificclass').select2();
```

When page first renders it looks as expected the `DropDownList` has that tags view that Select2 provides.

Click the save button and the save process is done ***`async`*** without a page refresh, but the Select2 dropdown list loses it Select2 styling and now just looks like a regular dropdown.

If I try to apply the Select2 class to the CssClass property of the control then a JavaScript error occurs on the client. "*Uncaught query function not defined for Select2 selectControlName*"

Thoughts?

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue. Instead of giving the command in document.ready function, give it in pageLoad function. pageLoad function will get executed during partial post backs.

```
function pageLoad(sender, args) {
        $(".dropdownspecificclass").select2();
    }
```

Comment: this fixed my issue, interestingly because pageLoad gets executed during partial post backs ! thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As per the design and [documentation of select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) select html element doesn't need any special parsing (data is parsed from select's option tags), to limit the selector to only select elements(in above case "ASP.NET DropDownList" renders as select html element) I recommended below change

and

"Uncaught query function not defined for Select2" exception usually occurs for other than select element cases.

```
//Replace your selector by prefixing select as below and then give a try
$('select.dropdownspecificclass').select2();
```

Answer (score 1):

example code, asp.net dropdownlist with select2 and bootstrap:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Demo_Select2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Demo_Select2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>

<link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Content/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Content/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>


<script src="Scripts/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="Content/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Content/select2-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />


<script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad() {
        $(".js-example-placeholder-single").select2({
            theme: "bootstrap",
            placeholder: "Select Item",
            allowClear: true
        });
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form2" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <div class="container">

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" class="form-control" AutoPostBack="true">
                    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>test b1</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>test b2</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>test b3</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>

        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" class="form-control js-example-placeholder-single" AutoPostBack="true">
                    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>test c1</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>test c2</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>test c3</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" class="form-control js-example-placeholder-single" AutoPostBack="true">
                    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>test d1</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>test d2</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>test d3</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>

    </div>
</form>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the `select2` .It seems to be a known issue and I think you will definitely get some help from here:
[Conflicts between ASP.NET AJAX UpdatePanels & jQuery functions](http://weblogs.asp.net/hajan/make-them-to-love-each-other-asp-net-ajax-updatepanels-amp-javascript-jquery-functions).

There is a full explanation about jquery issues **after triggering any ajax** and also there are various suggested solution methods.

**BUT** if there is no problem with that above at all, you can try to **reinitialize** the `.select2()` to the `.done()` event of your async.

Comment: The version of JQuery we are using I believe gets around this for the client side binding of events. All the other responsive logic that uses Jquery continues to work.  We are using $(selector).on("click") for instance rather than $(selector).click. I believe on works like live and watches for changes.  By .done() do you mean the endRequestHandler?  We do reinitialize in the endRequestHandler with no success.